# Map Fragment adjust size

Tags: java, android, supportmapfragment

I have map fragment for the full screen view. and summary popup is invisible on the bottom of the screen.

```
  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/ap_fragement"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.apps.MainActivity" />

 <!--Summary View  -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/summary_popup"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffffff">

 <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#1A237E"/>

.......


</LinearLayout>
```

When map loads camera view is center of the device screen and when I make my summary page visible it loads on the bottom of the device screen.

How can I move the map fragment to the top half of the device screen to show the selected/user location? Like UBER does when we request a ride.

I want to move the camera or set some different layout size on fragment view.

Comment: I've downvoted and reported your abusive remarks to moderators. Please try to refrain from txtspk here - it is rather lazy. You should, furthermore, be grateful that someone took the time to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ap_fragement).getView().setLayoutParams();
```

will resize the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it. You can re-arrange your layouts and 
manage things dynamically or have a look at [this](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) library.

Comment: I dont think new library for this solution. I think some mathematical workaround will do.